# Codeigniter Uploading files into gallery folder

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, upload, relational

This is what im trying to do in codeigniter:

I have member profile pages that all have their own gallery of photos. The user to be able to login and upload photos. I want the photos to then be placed inside of a folder with the usersname. So if the directory doesnt exsit for the user i want it to be created once he uploads a photo. The last thing of this is I want those photos uploaded to relate to that user and display on his profile page.

What I have working:

I can upload photos but it goes inside of the regular upload folder, I can also see the filename inside of the database that relates to that photo and I can view the files.

I need the user photos to be created inside of a folder with the username or id. and only the user photos to be displayed on his page. here is my gallery model:

```
<?php

class Gallery_model extends CI_Model{
    // initalizes the gallery path variable
    var $gallery_path;
    var $gallery_path_url;
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        //sets the gallery path to applications folder and gallery image path
        $this->gallery_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../portfolio');
        $this->gallery_path_url = base_url().'portfolio/';
    }

    function do_upload(){

        $config = array(
            // requried variable allowed types is needed also delcared the upload path to gallery path
            'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png',
            'upload_path' => $this->gallery_path,
            'max_size' => 3000
        );

        // loads the library and sets where its going to go to
        $this->load->library('upload',$config);
        // this performs the upload operation

        $this->upload->do_upload();
        //returns data about upload ( file location )
        $image_data = $this->upload->data();

        $config = array(
            'source_image' => $image_data['full_path'],
            'new_image' => $this->gallery_path . '/thumbs',
            'maintain_ration' => true,
            'width' => 250,
            'height' => 220
        );



        $data = array(
          'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
          'category' => $this->input->post('category'),
          'filename' => $image_data['file_name'],
        );

        $this->db->insert('portfolio', $data );

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();

    }
    function get_images(){

        $files = scandir($this->gallery_path);
        // substracts these out of array
        $files = array_diff($files, array('.', '..','thumbs'));
        $images = array();

        foreach ($files as $file){
            $images [] = array(
                'url' => $this->gallery_path_url . $file,
                'thumb_url' => $this->gallery_path_url . 'thumbs/' .$file
            );
        }
        return $images;
    }
}
```

and here is my view:

```
        function gallery(){
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $data = array(
            //$session_id = $this->session->userdata('session_id')
        ); // if no data is there and you wont get an error
            if($query = $this->user_model->get_profile())
        {
            $data['records'] = $query;


        }
        // loads the model. if the upload posts, call the do model method from the gallery model Model.
        $this->load->model('gallery_model');
        if ($this->input->post('upload')){
            $this->gallery_model->do_upload();
        }
        // displays the images
        $data['images'] = $this->gallery_model->get_images();

        $data['main_content'] = '/pages/gallery';
        $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
    }
```

Comment: And what is your problem ? Which part of code is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

You see the original filename in the portfolio folder because you missed out the "file_name" config variable for the upload library. Example:

```
$config = array(
  // requried variable allowed types is needed also delcared the upload path to gallery path
    'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png',
    'upload_path' => $this->gallery_path,
    'max_size' => 3000,
    'file_name' => "the user id or username"
);
```

I also see that you do not have "overwrite" variable set. Can be an problem because you are storing the filename as username as CI will not overwrite the file when the user upload a new photo.